CSS Multiple Identical Calc Use vs Single Calc in Custom Property on Performance
I am trying to ascertain the difference between the performance impact of storing a css calc function in a css custom variable and using that variable multiple times vs simply using the css calc function multiple times.
Allow me to explain:
OPTION 1
  // lets there are many many many classes that are going to use calc(20rem - 10vh);
    .test-case: {
      // assume this is actually a more realistic and potentially complicated calc
      max-width: calc(20rem - 10vh);
    }

OPTION 2
:root {

  // assume this is actually a more realistic and potentially complicated calc
  --test-case: calc(20rem - 10vh);
}

// lets there are many many many classes that are going to use var(--test-case);
.test-case: {
  max-width: var(--test-case);
}

So both are obviously the same. However in Option 1, the css calc function was placed in ever occurrence of max-width. In Option 2 the CSS calc function (maybe) ran only once within the css variable with the output placed in any use of class.
Is there a performance issue here or is there absolutely nothing here.
*I know many will argue option 2 based on usability in the coding process but we can ternate this by sass or other methods and that is not the question. The question is performance difference (if any) of (maybe) executing multiple calc functions vs (maybe) only executing it once in the css custom property.

ran only once within the css variable with the output placed in any use of class. --> no, it doesn't work that way. The content of CSS variable is only evaluated when used inside a property so the calc() will run as many time as you will use it. Unless you consider the use of @property to register it but this is another story
